# EXC_BAD_ACCESS returning from Facebook Login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

Facebook Login was working fine, but it looks like something happened after update my Xcode to Version 9.3 (9E145).

It opens Facebook app, I click to accept (or continue after accept first time) and when returning to my app it crashes. The debug stops on AppDelegate saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).

The output only shows:

```
2018-04-03 17:06:14.668925-0300 MyApp[16461:9191788] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
2018-04-03 17:06:14.917096-0300 MyApp[16461:9192005] TIC Read Status [7:0x0]: 1:57
2018-04-03 17:06:14.917148-0300 MyApp[16461:9192005] TIC Read Status [7:0x0]: 1:57
2018-04-03 17:06:21.768963-0300 MyApp[16461:9192094] TIC Read Status [8:0x0]: 1:57
2018-04-03 17:06:21.769653-0300 MyApp[16461:9192094] TIC Read Status [8:0x0]: 1:57
2018-04-03 17:06:22.098146-0300 MyApp[16461:9192439] TIC Read Status [9:0x0]: 1:57
2018-04-03 17:06:22.098528-0300 MyApp[16461:9192439] TIC Read Status [9:0x0]: 1:57
```

Any idea?

Comment: Thanks for your clear question!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a similar problem, it was enough to add the above fragment of code to the AppDelegate.

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, options: options)
}
```